# Javascript Algorithm Attempting to Implement Call Back Function

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

A Narcissistic Number is a number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits in a given base. In this Kata, we will restrict ourselves to decimal (base 10).

For example, take 153 (3 digits):

```
1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153
```

and 1634 (4 digits):

```
1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1 + 1296 + 81 + 256 = 1634
```

The Challenge:

Your code must return true or false depending upon whether the given number is a Narcissistic number in base 10.

Error checking for text strings or other invalid inputs is not required, only valid integers will be passed into the function.

**My Code**

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
 
    let valString = value.toString().split('');
 
    let integerSet = valString.map((item)=>{
     return Number(item);
    })
   
    let keyFunc = function powerCalc(test){
      let a = test[test.length-1];
      return test.map((item)=>{
        return Math.pow(item, a);
      }).reduce((total, item)=>{
        return total + item;
      }, 0);
    }

    console.log(keyFunc(153));

    if(keyFunc(integerSet)==value){
       return true;
     }
    else {
       return false;
     }
}


console.log(narcissistic(12432));
console.log(narcissistic(153));
```

**The Problem**

My console is saying that test.map is not a function.

How can I adjust that function to make it work?

Comment: `test` is the parameter of `powerCalc`/`keyFunc`. You're logging `keyFunc(153)` and `153` is obviously not an array -> remove `console.log(keyFunc(153))` or wrap `153` in an array

Comment: Appreciated :) Im getting these errors when I test it, any ideas? Narcissistic Function
 should find small numbers are all narcissistic
7 is narcissistic - Expected: true, instead got: false
Completed in 1ms
 should find these numbers are narcissistic
371 is narcissistic - Expected: true, instead got: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small mistakes:

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
 
    let valString = value.toString().split('');
 
    let integerSet = valString.map((item)=>{
     return Number(item);
    })
   
    let keyFunc = function powerCalc(test){
      let a = test.length;  // <------- "raised to the power of the number of digits"
      return test.map((item)=>{
        return Math.pow(item, a);
      }).reduce((total, item)=>{
        return total + item;
      }, 0);
    }

    // console.log(keyFunc(153)); // <-- This was throwing an error

    if(keyFunc(integerSet)==value){
       return true;
     }
    else {
       return false;
     }
}

console.log(narcissistic(12432));// false
console.log(narcissistic(153));  // true
console.log(narcissistic(371));  // true
console.log(narcissistic(7));    // true
```

And with a bit of rewriting:

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
    const integerSet = value.toString().split('').map(Number);
    const pow = integerSet.length;
    
    const sum = integerSet.reduce((total, item) => total + Math.pow(item, pow), 0);

    return sum == value;
}

console.log(narcissistic(12432));// false
console.log(narcissistic(153));  // true
console.log(narcissistic(371));  // true
console.log(narcissistic(7));    // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function narcissistic(value) {


// Code me to return true or false
  let n = Array.from(String(value)).length
  
  let total = Array.from(String(value)).reduce(function(sum, el) {
    return sum + el**n
  }, 0)
  
  if(value === total) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Leo, welcome to SO!
Thanks for posting an answer, remember to add some explanation to your code then your answer looks more complete!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more concise and readable version of Leo's answer

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  const digitsLength = Array.from(String(value)).length
  const exponentsTotal = Array.from(String(value)).reduce((sum, digit) => sum + digit**digitsLength, 0)
    
  return value === exponentsTotal ? true : false
}
```