# Confusing on Reduce and Arrow function

Tags: javascript, function, reduce

I am now looking at the following post
[Javascript Algorithm Attempting to Implement Call Back Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471704/javascript-algorithm-attempting-to-implement-call-back-function). I can understand the other parts but particularly confuse at the following code.
 `const sum = integerSet.reduce((total, item) => total + Math.pow(item, pow), 0);`. 
So, what is the purpose of adding 0 at the end and if we change from arrow function to normal function would it be change to this? 
`sum = integerSet.reduce(function(total, item) { return total + Math.pow(item,power),0; })`  
I have searched up the several reduce methods usage but still can't get the clear figure of how he use there so I decided to ask it here.

Comment: The arrow function ends at the `,`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0 gives you the starting point. From there everything will be calculated "on top" of this accumulator. So in your example the 0 would be the `item` to start with.

Comment: But doesn't reduce method particularly start "total" from null then add after working "item" to it.  In reduce(a,b)=> a + b, a starts from null according to my book, thats why I am confusing

Comment: @echo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters

Comment: @echo In `[1, 2].reduce((a, b) => ...)`, the function is called directly with `a = 1, b = 2`. In `[1, 2].reduce((a, b) => ..., 0)`, it's called initially as `a = 0, b = 1`.

Comment: `null` is an object and zero is a number. so you do have different datatypes. it might be possible but somewhat clumsy to start with null. but maybe there is a usecase for that too.